# Zoom-in functionality on mouse scroll in highcharts scatter plot

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, mouseevent, scatter-plot

Does highcharts scatter plot have zoom-in on mouse scroll functionality. I searched but was not able to find a solution.  If yes please help in this. I using typescript for this

If there is an example available please share

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts supports mouse wheel zoom functionality since 11.1 version.
It is available for Highcharts Stock out of the box; for Highcharts Core you need to load the module:

**Example:**

```
import HC_Mouse_Wheel_Zoom from 'highcharts/modules/mouse-wheel-zoom';
HC_Mouse_Wheel_Zoom(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-woj4hs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.zooming.mouseWheel